# Do I need "as well" in the end of this sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I have the following sentence.

> The deadline for problem 2 is Sept 1st.
>
> Moreover, since there is no class nor office time on Friday, I extend
>   the deadline for problem 1 to Sept 1st as well.

I feel really uncomfortable with the second sentence. First of all, should I write "there is no classes nor office time" or just "class"? Also, do I need "as well" in the end of second sentence?

Moreover, if you have any other suggestion to make this sentence sounds better. Please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that jumps out at me as sounding off is the use of nor. [While nor isn't always used with neither](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/when-use-nor), it usually is, and I think it would sound better with neither, or with or (since the "no" is a negative that carries through)

> Moreover, since there is neither class nor office time...

of

> Moreover, since there is no class or office time...

I also agree with user3169's suggestion to change "I extend" to "I am extending".

As far as your other specific questions:

Class is perfectly fine. But if you did want to say classes, you'd have to do some other rearranging ("since there *are* neither classes nor office *times*...").

You don't *need* "as well" at the end, but it makes the message clearer. Without it, it seems like one of the two dates given might be incorrect, because it would be a little strange to reference the same date twice without acknowledging somehow that it is the same.

So final full sentence:

> Moreover, since there is neither class nor office time on Friday, I am extending the deadline for problem 1 to Sept 1st as well.

Answer (score 0):

*time* as used here (as *class time* or *office time*) does not refer to a specific time. So I think your example is fine with one change. Due to the continuing time reference, use "am extending":

> Moreover, since there is no class nor office time on Friday, I *am extending* the deadline for problem 1 to Sept 1st as well.

You could say "there *are* no classes", but then it would conflict with "there *is* no office time".